# Accessing Returned Function Values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, destruction

Consider the following function:

```
def function
  return 1, 2
end
```

How can I set `a` equal to 1 and `b` equal to 2, assuming `a` and `b` are variables?

Please don't recommend `a=1` and `b=2`, the point is to understand how to access what the function has returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do using a comma:

```
a, b = function
```

In fact, `function` returns an array of two elements:

```
def function
  return 1,2
end
=> nil 
function
=> [1, 2]
```

And you are *desconstructing* the array - that is each element from the array goes to one variable.

**fun fact:** The keyword `return` is needed in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a multiple assignment:

```
def function
  return 1, 2
end

a, b = function
```